# Reshaping Inputs that contain continuous and discrete values

Tags: machine-learning

The inputs I am using are 2xN, where the first 1xN row are continuous numbers, and the second 1xN row are discrete numbers (that encodes a specific class out of 7 possible classes). I expect there to be a relation between vertically adjacent pairs.

I am looking to use a neural net for a multi-class classifier on this input, but am unsure of how to reshape my data for forward propagation in a way that makes sense.

What is a feasible way to reshape my data into 1x2N for forward propogation that makes sense?

edit:

Example input:

```
input_features = [[99.3, 22.1, 41.7], [1, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "1xN row is a continuous number", how can row be a number? Do you mean number**s**? It would be good to provide example of your data, as the description is pretty unclear

Comment: Yes, sorry I was clearly in a rush when I wrote this. Please let me know if it's still unclear

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know something more than "there might be some kind of relation", you should just flatten the array and pass it as a vector - NN can (in theory) find such realtions on its own (given enough data).

What are the other options? If you suspect that there is a **single** relation, such that it is true for every single column, then you might want to construct specific neural net. One option is to have a convolution of size 2x1 (single column) in the input layer. On the other hand - if you create large enough set of kernels, this will be able to model more complex relations too. In such case - leave it as a matrix (think about it as an image). There is nothing wrong with discrete values, as long as they are in the reasonable scale.

In general - you will actually just work with specific wiring of the net, not reshaping of an array (however, implementations of conv nets actually use shape to do the work for you, as described).

Comment: What about preprocessing (I'm doubtful I'll use raw values)? For image processing, my understanding is that usually one should take all inputs and subtract each input by their collective mean, then divide by the standard deviation. This type of pre-processing doesn't make intuitive sense in this case, as it would be assigning different "distances" between classes when preprocessing the discrete values.

Comment: I would argue that for image processing it is enough to scale to a reasonable interval, there is no need for centering. If you have doubts in terms of preprocessing due to some expert knowledge about the data then you are the only one who can design preprocessing - as you seem to suggest that there is some hidden relation in between values